# React Native User Input Data Into API Link

Tags: ios, api, react-native

I need to make it so the user can **fill out the form** with the **sport** they want to find from **Google Places API**  on the filters page click **submit** and have the form they just filled out **replace the text in the api link** to filter the results. After some research im pretty sure you use **+this.state.variable+**  in the **API Link** and in the **form** you use **value={this.state.variable}**

**My Fetch Request on the Results Page**

```
fetchData() {
   fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=GooglePlacesAPIKey&radius=5000&keyword=+this.state.variable+&location=+this.state.geolocation+')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseData) => {
       this.setState({
           dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.results),
           isLoading: false
       });

   })
   .done();
 }
```

**Filters Page**

```
render(){
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.loginContainer}>

   <TextInput
    style={styles.searchInput}
    value={this.state.variable} 
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>

   <TouchableHighlight
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={this.goToSpotlight.bind(this)}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Search </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight> 
   </View>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchData() {
   fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=GooglePlacesAPIKey&radius=5000&keyword=+this.state.variable+&location=+this.state.geolocation+')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseData) => {
       this.setState({
           dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.results),
           isLoading: false
       });

   })
   .done();
 }
```

You have an error in your query. It should be done by this way:

```
var query = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=GooglePlacesAPIKey&radius=5000&keyword=${this.state.variable}&location=${this.state.geolocation}`;
```

Comment: Do I have to attach anything to the Touchablehighlight? or just the on change on the textinput. Becuase the form I have is on another page

Comment: Do you want to call fetchData by pressing your TouchableHighlight? If so then you need to do this thing:
`...
   <TouchableHighlight
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={this.fetchData.bind(this)}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Search </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight> 
...`

Comment: Does it matter if what im submitting and the results are on a different page because i don't think its picking up the fetchData from the API fetch on the results page. Thank you for the help I really appreciate it

Comment: Could you specify what you want to get?

Comment: I just want the ability for the user to type in a sport which they would like to find a location for using google places on the filters page, then have them click submit and the sport they typed in to be inserted into the api link on the next page which is the page to display all the locations from the api. i think i need to use passprops

Comment: Ah, I got it. You want to pass props from one component to another right?
You should read about [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).
This goal can be reached by other ways, but I can't say how can you do that without your code.